# Having problems understanding how getpackagemanager() is derived from getactivity() kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I was looking through some docs when I stumbled upon this line of code

```
if (activity?.packageManager?.resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

I was puzzled as I can't seem to find `packageManager` as a method in the activity class, how did the activity instance use the dot operator with `packagemanager` if it is not one of the `Activity` class properties?

Upon further digging, the `packageManager` method can be found in the `ContextWrapper` class, any idea how this works? I am unfamiliar with this syntax. Sorry for the Noob question.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: `packageManager` is an attribute or getter (could be called `getPackageManager` if it's defined in a Java class) defined on something activity inherits from. What is your actual question? Are you wondering how to know what methods are available to call in an activity? Or how Kotlin calls a Java getter using a method-access-looking syntax?

Comment: I am trying to figure out where the `packageManager`(kotlin) also known as `getpackageManager`(java) method came from. From the code above the `activity`(kotlin) also known as the `getActivity`(java) method is part of the `Fragment` class. 

The `activity` method returns an instance of the `Activity` the fragment is on. However, I can't seem to find the `Packagemanager` method as part of the `activity` class. So I was wondering where the `Packagemanager` method came from in the above code. This is based on Android Studio btw